# Add invisible buttons / clickable areas onto Tkinter Canvas

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I am writing a game, which has nodes which are supposed to be clickable. I was thinking of implementing these as ovals with callback functions using tag binding. The only problem with that is it seems hidden objects on the canvas do not respond to events.

Is there a good way to implement areas of the screen which are clickable (ex. hitbox) which would be invisible to the user?

Answer (score 0):

When you create the oval (canvas.create_oval), pass the arguments

```
fill=""
```

and

```
outline=""
```

options to keep the oval transparent and remove the outline. The oval is now effective hidden.